# preg_replace replace whole string

Tags: php, preg-replace

my preg_replace replaces my whole string instead of just the bit where the expression fits.

Code:

```
http://beta.yapaste.com/bd
```

This is what I want replaced:

```
<table id=\"post24100391\" style=\"width: 100%;\" class=\"p4\" >
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: you're expression starts with table and ends with /table, what did you expect?? What do you want to replace exactly?

Comment: Why is the HTML escaped and why don't you use DOM like any sane person would do and like I suggested in your previous question?

Comment: I couldent make it work with https.

Comment: @Victor: How is HTTPS related to that? Do you know what it is?

Comment: @Victor What is it you want to have replaced now? And why are the quotes escaped?

Comment: It seems every day people are asking to parse HTML with regular expressions. But its a bad idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454 and http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0081_parse_html_extract_data_from_html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes..... that regex matches the entire table.... it will replace the entire string with $replace.

what is it you want to replace?

You could use capturing replacement...

```
preg_replace("/(<table.*?>).*(<\/table>)/","\$1$replace\$2},$str);
```

Or you could use a non-capturing group around the parts to not replace...

e.g.

```
preg_replace("/(?:<table.*?>).*(?:<\/table>)/",$replace,$str) //not tested, though
```

**EDIT** in response to OP change

```
preg_replace("/<table.*?>/",$replace,$str);
```

You wanted to use lazy capturing *?